# How to install sage from repository?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, sagemath

Instructions [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SAGE) did not work.

Instructions:

```
apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
apt-get update
apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

After last command I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sagemath-upstream-binary is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sagemath-upstream-binary' has no installation candidate
```

How to overcome?

**UPDATE**

Check command

```
$ sudo grep sage /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -R
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/aims-sagemath-trusty.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/aims-sagemath-trusty.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/aims-sagemath-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/aims-sagemath-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/aims-sagemath-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Works fine for me. I'd guess your first command didn't run successfully. See if `grep sage /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -R` lists any files. Are you behind a proxy, or firewall, etc.?

Comment: Are you on 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: 32 bit and virtual

Comment: Although you wanted to do this from the package, keep in mind you could also install from source - it's really not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sage PPA currently only publishes a binary package for 64-bit systems:

```
$ grep '^Package' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aims*_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aims_sagemath_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: sagemath-upstream-binary
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aims_sagemath_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: sagemath-optional
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aims_sagemath_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages:Package: sagemath-optional
```

The [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty) for that package lists only `amd64` in the Builds section.

Even in a VM, there's no reason not to use 64-bit. So install 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: So you cannot do `apt-add-repository` here, since I get also the error `Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~aims/+archive/sagemath: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)`. So the default way to install Sage is to download the 800MB file and just install. They have removed the non-Debian package from apt-get.

Comment: @Masi are you behind a firewall or proxy or something? What do you mean, non-Debian package? A PPA only provides Debian packages.

Comment: No proxy and no firewall, just default Debian 8.1 which should be compatible with 14.04. Can you give a clear preview how you add the package in Sage. I got the error which I don not understand.